# Postgres query to modify prefix from AA112233 to ZZ112233

Tags: sql, postgresql

To update the existing user id prefix from AA to ZZ, can you help me to find simple update query which will update all the existing user prefix from AA to ZZ

Comment: Not my downvote, but it probably happened because your question is thin, shows no data, effort, etc.

Comment: No worries i found the solution update distributor  set column = replace(column,substr(column,1),concat('ZZ',substr(column,3)))

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my question and it is

```
update table  set <field>= replace(<field>,substr(<field>,1),concat('FUN',substr(<field>,3))) where <field>='AA112233';
```